# Web Push y Node.js en Godaddy

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs, phpmyadmin

estoy trabajando en un proyecto que consiste en la interacción de dos usuarios de distinta categoria, por ejemplo cliente y administrador, de tal forma que el cliente envía cierta información por un formulario y se guarda en una base de datos mysql (que administro desde phpMyAdmin), y el administrador solicita información a la base de datos para saber si algún cliente a enviado datos por el formulario. Todo esto lo tengo en godaddy alojado en un hosting compartido, y cabe recalcar que el cliente y el administrador están en tablas diferentes en la base de datos y también inician sesion en archivos php diferentes.

El punto es que necesito que el administrador sepa que hay un nuevo registro en la tabla **"informacionDeFormularios"** sin necesidad de que lo solicite. Lo mejor que pude hacer es que mediante ajax se solicite información de la tabla y se verifique si hay nuevos registros, en caso haya nuevos registros se manda una notificación al administrador avisando que hay nuevos registros, y con un setInterval hago que se repita el ajax cada 30 segundos, de esta forma el administrador puede estar viendo otra página o estar en otra aplicación pero el script se sigue ejecutando cada 30 segundos, lo malo es que si el administrador cierra la página deja de funcionar el script y ya no se le avisa que hay nueva información, eso le obliga a tener siempre abierta la página aunque puede estar viendo otras página u otras aplicaciones.

Traté de instalar node.js en godaddy y lo logré creando una carpeta **"bin"** en **home/usuario/** y puse dentro de **home/usuario/bin** el archivo node.js, npm y npx,  y cuando ejecuto por SSH **node archivo.js &** lo ejecuta bien (aunque no sé si funciona el & porque no sé cómo comprobarlo). No me funciona el npm pero instalo modulos en mi pc y los subo a godaddy como cualquier otro archivo. La verdad tengo muy poca idea de como funciona node.js ya que todos los ejemplos que veo son apuntando el servidor a **localhost:3000**, cosa que no me sirve porque yo ya tengo todos mis archivos funcionando muy bien en **home/usuario/public_html** con mi dominio **[www.dominio.com](http://www.dominio.com)**. También vi que en el **.htacces** redirigen todo a **localhost:3000**, cosa que tampoco me sirve porque mi **.htacces** redirige todo a **https** y como vuelvo a repetir todo mis archivos php, js, etc. funcionan muy bien en mi dominio actual.

Entonces ya que no encuentro absolutamente ningún tutorial que diga como implementar el módulo **web push** (y los otros modulos que lo acompañan) para crear web push junto con las notificaciones en mi web en la vida real con un service worker, osea no en mi pc sino en godaddy donde ya está todo mi proyecto, y sin tener que malograr todo mi proyecto que ya se encuentra en el dominio **https://www.dominio.com** (es un dominio falso obviamente). Porfavor espero que alguien me explique cómo hacerlo, porque necesito que le lleguen notificaciones en tiempo real al administrador de que hay nueva informacion en la bd **base** tabla **informacionDeFormularios**, incluso si no tiene abierto la página ni nada. (Porfavor que sea explicado para alguien que no tiene idea de como usar node.js y teniendo en cuenta que actualmente ya interactua el administrador con el cliente en sus respectivas páginas php aunque no en tiempo real sino cada 30 segundo por ajax)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es del tamaño del Sahara, por lo amplia que es. Me parece que confundes `hosting` con `servidor de aplicaciones`. Tienes una web en un servidor de `hosting`, pero ahora necesitas implementar un servicio con alguna aplicación, en este caso usas NodeJS. A menos que tu servidor de `hosting` te permita la ejecución de un servicio o aplicación, la única forma de levantar tu aplicativo en NodeJS es contratar un servidor de aplicación. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) es muy popular para desarrollo...

Comment: Pero para producción tal vez quieras usar algo más potente o diferente, eso va a depender de tus necesidades y presupuesto. En cuanto a si usar RSS Feeds o Server Push o implementar websockets, todo es cuestión de opiniones y de tus requerimientos específicos. Actualmente la tecnología más popular para el tipo de mensajes que deseas implementar es [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/WebSockets). Muchas aplicaciones de chat utilizan este tipo de tecnología (Whatsapp por ejemplo). Espero que eso te de una idea de lo que debes buscar. Implementarlo, es otro tema bastante largo.